# What does strings like "com.google.process.gapps" mean?

Tags: reverse-dns

I've seen things like `com.google.process.gapps` in a lot of places, like Android and Flatpak, etc. What does it mean? It looks like a domain reversed.

Comment: Good question.  MacOS does the same with preference files etc stored in `com.apple.<WhateverProgram>` format so this naming convention seems to extend beyond Android.  I added that as an extra tag if that is OK.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_domain_name_notation

Comment: @Doug Deden  - that Wiki article doesn't seem to address reason though.

Comment: It mentions it, but it is admittedly rather vague. It is "...a simple way of reducing name-space collisions...". Also, from https://web.archive.org/web/20060508013146/http://www.gnu.org/software/java/why-gnu-packages.txt, "Using the reverse domain name is an arbitrary convention, that uses a specific property of an organization to generate a unique name."

Comment: @lx07 The reason for using URL is to reduce namespace collision. The reason for reversing is for sorting (most significant part of the URL comes first this way).

Comment: Could you put that as an answer so I can accept it?